# BASH Script hangs after some processing on my Desktop running Ubuntu 18, while works fine on a Red Hat server

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu, recursion, process

I have been running below script on a Red Hat server, and it works fine and finishes the job. the file I am feeding it, contains half a million lines in it (approximately 500000 lines), and that's why (to finish it faster) I have added an '&' at the end of while loop block

But now I have setup a Desktop with 8 GB of RAM running Ubuntu 18.04 on it, and running the same code only finishes a few thousand lines and then hangs. I read a bit about it and increased the stack limit to unlimited as well and still it hung after 80000 lines or so, Any suggestions about how can I optimize the code or tune my PC parameters to always finish the job?

```
while read -r CID60
do
{
  OLT=$(echo "$CID60" | cut -d"|" -f5)
  ONID=${OLT}:$(echo "$CID60" | cut -d, -f2 | sed 's/ //g ; s/).*|//')
  echo $ONID,$(echo "$CID60" | cut -d"|" -f3)  >> 
  $localpath/CID_$logfile.csv
} &
done < $localpath/$CID7360
```

Comment: You are sending around half million jobs to the background in a very short time. There are not enough resources in your computer to spawk half a million new processes (and the processes they spawn themselves: 3 extra bash, 3 echos, 3 cut, one sed). You can either increase the resorces in your computer or reduce the rate at which you start new processes.

Comment: I am currently running above code without '&' and it seems running fine, but it will take very long time to finish the job. I need to know how I can finish the job quickly.

Comment: It's not an all or nothing thing. Don't start all the processes at once, but don't start them one by one either. Start a bunch of them simultaneously and don't go over a certain number of simultaneous jobs.